# Base64 encoding btoa

Tags: java, angular, encoding

I am encoding some text on my frontend part using btoa function:

```
const encodedText = btoa(searchText);
```

This seems to work totally fine and decoding goes like this on backend part:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(searchedText);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Which also works fine. However, this seems to fail when using ü letter. My program encodes it as A==, and as far as I know, it should be w7w=

I am not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
const encodedText = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(searchText)));
```

instead to encode unicode characters first.

See [Unicode strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#Unicode_strings) and [The "Unicode Problem"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem) for further reading.

```js
console.log(btoa('ü'));
console.log(btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent('ü'))));
```

Comment: apparently it was enough to use encodeURIComponent(btoa(searchText))